# xquery replacing value if node exist

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-update

I'm working with xQuery and I'm trying to replace the value of `test` element if the element tag `Active` does not exist under the `User` element.

(I added quotes to be able to display it here properly...)

```
declare @testXML xml = '
<USER>
  <ID>10</ID>
  <TEST>1</TEST>
</USER>'

set @testXML.modify('if (exists(/USER/Active)=false)
                 then replace value of /USER/TEST with "2"
                 else ()') 
select @testXML
```

For this I get this error:

> XQuery [modify()]: Syntax error near 'value', expected 'else'.

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to embed `replace value of ... with ..` in an expression.

From [replace value of (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx)

```
replace value of 
      Expression1 
with
      Expression2
```

You can use something like this instead:

```sql
set @testXML.modify('replace value of (/USER[not(Active)]/TEST/text())[1] 
                     with "2"')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3975)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but do you know why the if then else doesn't work for me?